# How to prevent an infinite loop in react using Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, In that I have two buttons I applied state and functions to both buttons but it is showing error like this. please help me to resolve this issue.
It is showing error like this Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

This is my code App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "antd"
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [buttonOne, setButtonOne] = useState({
    backgroundColor: "#b5e5f6",
    color: "black",
    border: "#b5e5f6"
  })

  const buttonOneFun = () => {
    setButtonOne({
      backgroundColor: "#eaeaea",
    color: "black",
    border: "#eaeaea"
    })
  }

  const [buttonTwo, setButtonTwo] = useState({
    backgroundColor: "#eaeaea",
    color: "black",
    border: "#eaeaea"
  })

  const buttonTwoFun = () => {
    setButtonTwo({
      backgroundColor: "#b5e5f6",
      color: "black",
      border: "#b5e5f6"
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button style={{backgroundColor: buttonOne.backgroundColor, border: buttonOne.border, color: buttonOne.color}} className="one" type="primary">First</Button>
      <Button onClick={() => buttonTwoFun(), buttonOneFun()} style={{backgroundColor: buttonTwo.backgroundColor, color: buttonTwo.color, border: buttonTwo.border}} className="two" type="primary">Second</Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: I'm not certain, but should `() => buttonTwoFun(), buttonOneFun()` be `() => { buttonTwoFun(); buttonOneFun() }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap this two function inside a `{}`, you will not see this error anymore but I would suggest you to just using one function in `onClick` and setting your both `states` inside this function.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "antd"
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [buttonOne, setButtonOne] = useState({
    backgroundColor: "#b5e5f6",
    color: "black",
    border: "#b5e5f6"
  })

 const [buttonTwo, setButtonTwo] = useState({
    backgroundColor: "#eaeaea",
    color: "black",
    border: "#eaeaea"
  })

  const buttonOneAndTwoFun = () => {
    setButtonOne({
      backgroundColor: "#eaeaea",
    color: "black",
    border: "#eaeaea"
    });
   setButtonTwo({
      backgroundColor: "#b5e5f6",
      color: "black",
      border: "#b5e5f6"
    })
  }

   
 

  return (
    <div>
      <Button style={{backgroundColor: buttonOne.backgroundColor, border: buttonOne.border, color: buttonOne.color}} className="one" type="primary">First</Button>
      <Button onClick={() => buttonOneAndTwoFun()} style={{backgroundColor: buttonTwo.backgroundColor, color: buttonTwo.color, border: buttonTwo.border}} className="two" type="primary">Second</Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing this way

```
return (
<div>
  <Button style={{backgroundColor: buttonOne.backgroundColor, border: buttonOne.border, color: buttonOne.color}} className="one" type="primary">First</Button>
  <Button onClick={() => {
      buttonTwoFun(); 
      buttonOneFun();
  }} style={{backgroundColor: buttonTwo.backgroundColor, color: buttonTwo.color, border: buttonTwo.border}} className="two" type="primary">Second</Button>
 </div>
)
```

Comment: Hi @Chanuka Sandeepa, I tried your code it is showing error like this Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions